# Minimal Sufficient Statistics

Tags: statistics, sufficient-statistics

Minimal sufficient statistics are supposed to have the lowest dimension among all sufficient statistics. Then, is any sufficient statistic having the same dimension (as the mss) a minimal sufficient statistic? If the answer is no, is there any simple counterexample?

Comment: A nice answer on this is here. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/454476/sufficient-statistics-are-not-unique#:~:text=Sufficient%20statistics%20are%20not%20unique%3A%20Any%20one-to-one%20transformation,a%20sufficient%20statistic%20is%20again%20a%20sufficient%20statistic.